# Tensorflow super simple model? 10 inputs, 1 output, so 11 trainable parameters

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am a little new to Tensorflow, I'm using TensorflowJS, but feel free to post your Python code.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

I want to train a simple model of 10 inputs and 1 output.
I have 10 inputs of consistent dimensions *[255,255]*.

The output should be of size *[255,255]* aswell, and should add each of the inputs according to some weights. So there will be 10 weights (+bias), the output is simply a lineair combination of the inputs.

I want to train these 10 weights so the result is as close as possible to a **validation matrix** of size *[255,255]*. I think the absoluteDifference as a loss function is best for this.

However, I have no idea how to make this trainable model in Tensorflow? So far this is what I got:

```
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [255,255], units: 10, activation: 'relu'}));
/* Prepare the model for training: Specify the loss and the optimizer. */
model.compile({loss: 'absoluteDifference', optimizer: 'momentum'});
```

Answer (score 1):

In python it would be something this:

```
   model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(255, 255, 10)), # 10 inputs of 255x255 
        keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='relu'), 
        keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid') #assuming it's binary classification, we use sigmoid
    ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True))
```

Quick note that in TF 2.0, `absolutedifference` loss does not exist. You'd have to use [TF 1.X](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/losses/absolute_difference)

You can go through a detailed example of it in [TF Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification)

EDIT:
Model Summary

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten_3 (Flatten)          (None, 650250)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 9)                 5852259   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 10        
=================================================================
Total params: 5,852,269
Trainable params: 5,852,269
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Many thanks! Hmm why the last dense layer (sigmoid) after the dense relu layer? Wouldnt this create more than 11 trainable parameters?

Comment: Updated the code now. You'll have 10 parameter at last layer now.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm do I really need the reLU layer with 5m params? I dont want to modify/look at individual values in the [255,255] input. I just want to smash the 10 inputs together with a single weight for an [255,255] input.

Comment: The input of each layer is the output of previous layer. If you have an input with size `255x255` that means you have exactly that many inputs per unit i.e. `65025`. If you wish to reduce the parameter to just 10 inputs, you have to feed in input of `1x1` per unit. Also, You can remove the relu layer but it still won't give you just 10 inputs.